# Google Calendar API - 403 error

Tags: html, error-handling, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to set up an application using the Google Calendar API. I set up all the credentials and set the authorized JavaScript page equal to `http://localhost:8000` as suggested within the quick start guide at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js. When I try to run the file on `localhost:8000/quickstart.html` it will show the basis page but no information. I can click the authenticate button and it will allow me to authenticate my account to use the Calendar application, however nothing will show up information-wise. Checking the console, the following errors are present:

> Get `https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&orderBy=startTime&showDeleted=false&singleEvents=true&timeMin=2017-08-11T20%3A58%3A29.156Z` 403 ()

and

> Uncaught {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Access Not Configured. Calendar API has not been used in project 440480151645 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar.googleapis.com/overview?project=44080151645` then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","extendedHelp":"`https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar.googleapis.com/overview?project=44080151645`"}],"code":403,"message":"Access Not Configured. Calendar API has not been used in project 44080151645 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar.googleapis.com/overview?project=44080151645` then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}}

However, going to the supplied link only says that I do not have access to the calendar.googleapis.com api and will not let me enable my Google Calendar or use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google calendar uses [Oauth2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for authorization. There are three essential components of this. If any of these are missing, authorization will not happen properly and you'll get a 403.

1. Access token - the google calendar API saves an access token to your
   /.credentials folder by default. Your application will need to be
   able to read this file (wherever it may be), otherwise you will have
   to manually authorize API calls with every request.
2. client_secret.json - this is a necessary file to authorize your
   *application itself* as a client of google. When you created a clientID and such using the google developer portal, this file was
   created, and must also be read by your application.
3. Scopes - The scope is what level of access you have. It is by
   default in the quickstart set to "read-only", which could be why
   you're getting 403. If you want to change the scope, you're going to
   have to edit **both** the line of code in the quickstart and either
   modify the access token or get a new one to reflect that change.

I have gotten this error before, but that was before I understood Oauth2. If the problem isn't in any of these, it's likely something that you selected in the developer console. Let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: I have all three key components, but am not utilizing the secret as I do not see where in the quickstart.html it is required. What am I to do with the secret code?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out! I had forgotten to activate the API within the Google Development Portal. They should really put a big poster that reminds you when you make a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t), try setting the `Referrers` to `Any referrer allowed` for your project (just leave the field empty) in the [Google Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com) if it is not already like that.

To do this, go to your [Google Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com) and open API & Auth / Credentials and click `Edit allowed referrers` empty the input field.

Additional reference:

- [Google Calendar API v3 Access Not Configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982523/google-calendar-api-v3-access-not-configured)
- [403 error with message:Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020898/403-error-with-messageaccess-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-conso)
- [Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144299/access-not-configured-the-api-google-api-is-not-enabled-for-your-project-pl)